# Vue 2.7 Array of objects losing reactivity when modified

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, composition, vue-composition-api

I've recently managed to upgrade our codebase to Vue 2.7 in the hopes of being able to start using the CompAPI, but I'm having some issues with it.

The feature that I'm having an issue with is the editing of a particular item in a reactive array. To keep things simple, the feature is related to timetracking, which is presented to the user as an array of entry objects, the details aren't terribly important here.

The template itself looks like this

```js
<template>
  <ul>
    <h1>{{ totalDuration }}</h1>
    <li v-for="entry in reversedEntries">{{ entry.duration }}</li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

The below is all in a `<script setup lang="ts">` tag

```js
import { ref, computed, onMounted } from "vue";

const entries = ref<Entry[]>([]);

const reversedEntries = computed(() => [...entries.value].reverse());
// Calculates the total duration of all entries
const totalDuration = computed(() => [...entries.value].map(({ duration }) => {...})
```

The actual fetching logic happens `onMounted`;

```js
onMounted(async () => { await fetchEntries() })

async function fetchEntries() {
  // Details are unimportant, but ultimately the entries are set like this
  await callToApi().then((response) => entries.value = response.data);
}
```

So far, so good. The data gets fetched, the computeds all show up properly and the list shows as expected to the user. The problem comes from when I try let a user edit an existing time entry, which involves a call to a different endpoint, similar to the below:

```
async function updateEntry() {
  await callToEditApi().then((response) => entries.value = response.data);
}
```

At this point, the `entries` ref object loses all reactivity, and the computeds silently fail, which is only visible from in the Vue devtools (UI-wise things stay the same, meaning the old list with the old entry stays visible as it was before). In the devtools themselves I get 2 errors on my computeds, both of which say that `entries.value` is `undefined`.

I've tried a variety of ways of setting this data like modifying the specific array index being modified, and various combinations of `Vue.set` and `vm.$set`, but none of it makes a difference and ultimately for some reason, the `entries` array loses all reactivity.

I also want to note that *pushing* to the `entries` array works just fine. For example when a user adds a new entry, it looks like this and works just fine, properly triggering all the computeds to redraw as they should

```js
async function addEntry(entry) {
  await callToApi().then(() => entries.value.push(entry));
}
```

This doesn't happen in Vue 3, however, so is this just a limitation of the Composition API when used inside Vue 2.7? If not, is there a workaround here (excluding the OptionsAPI which is what I'm converting this component away from, obviously).

Comment: Your code works when I put it into a snippet. Are you sure that `response.data` is not undefined?